# Complete nested partial class in child class

Tags: c#, inner-classes, partial-classes

I have two classes, A and B. B inherits from A.

Here is my problem : I have a constant ConstantA which is useful for the class A, but also for the child classes. I also have a constant ConstantB, which is specific to my class B.

Since I store my constants in a public static nested class, the Constants class in the child class hides the parents one. I tried making it a partial class, it does not help. Is there any way to solve this?

Here's an example :

```
public class A 
{
    public static partial class Constants
    {
        public const int ConstantA = 1;
    }
}

public class B : A 
{
    public static partial class Constants
    {
        public const int ConstantB = 1;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: If `ConstantA` is useful for all childs classes why not move it inside parent instead of a inner static class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to make `A` a partial class as well, and declare your B-specific constant separately from the `B` class itself:

```
public partial class A
{
    public static partial class Constants
    {
        public const int ConstantA = 1;
    }
}

public partial class A
{
    public static partial class Constants
    {
        public const int ConstantB = 1;
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    static void M()
    {
        int i = Constants.ConstantB;
        int j = Constants.ConstantA;
    }
}
```

That said, I'm skeptical that design is all that good. It has the effect of declaring your `ConstantB` value inside `A`, which seems contrary to the goal of encapsulation, assuming `ConstantB` really is relevant only to class `B`. If you declare it this way, `ConstantB` is accessible via *any* use of the `Constants` class, in any type.

But if you're okay with that, and are just trying to make sure the *declaration* of the constant stays with the `B` class, then the above will work.

Other options include going ahead and hiding (using the `new` keyword) the base `Constants` class, with the minor inconvenience of having to specify the base class as fully-qualified to access the base values (e.g. `A.Constants.ConstantA`), hiding the base class and having the `B.Constants` class inherit `A.Constants` (requires abandoning the `static` class attribute) or, IMHO much better, not using a nested class at all, and instead putting the `Constants` classes in their respective namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

Simply make your ConstantA an attribute of your parent class, putting this attribute in a nested class removes it from the scope of the inherited class.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want nested classes, you can leave the `static` keyword, and do inheritance for the `B.Constants` nested class:

```
public class A 
{
    public class Constants
    {
        public const int ConstantA = 1;
    }
}

public class B : A 
{
    public new class Constants : A.Constants
    {
        public const int ConstantB = 2;
    }
}
```

The usage will be the same.